# iOS app can not crash immediately when use Realm

Tags: ios, realm, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have used Realm in our iOS app because it is a replacement for SQLite & Core Data. Then I have found that when our app threw an exception but it could not crash immediately. It goes into a Realm recursive like the picture below. The app's UI is blocked more than ten seconds then the app crash. The most important thing is that I can not receive any crash logs use the Crashlytics developed by Twitter.

[image: Realm recursive]

Comment: This looks like a bad interaction between Realm and whichever library you're using that is using an `SSDK` prefix on their symbols. I'd suggest reporting this to both [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new) and the other framework vendor so they can investigate.

Comment: Did you find a solution?